# Jasperserver email scheduling and proxy server

Tags: java, tomcat6, jasperserver, proxy-server

I've having a slight problem and i'll like you so share you opinion experience on it.I've deployed a jasperserver on tomcat 6 in a environment where anything has to pass through the proxy server to have access to the internet.

i'm wondering about where to put the proxy params and credentials. at tomcat level or at jasperserver level ?I've seen that JavaMail does support retrieving or sending mail through proxy server.Another thing is that i've also seen that all Java Tcp can be configured using the Java Runtime to direct socket connection to the proxy server which can harm performance.

What other options do i have?

thanks for reading this!

Comment: Have you asked at http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperserver/forum/ ?